# $inf\{||x|| : x \in X , ||F(x)|| = \alpha\} = \frac{\alpha}{||F||}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $F \in B(X,Y), F\neq 0$ and $\alpha \geq 0$, then show that

$$inf\{||x|| : x \in X , ||F(x)|| = \alpha\} = \frac{\alpha}{||F||}$$

where $B(X,Y)$ is the set of all bounded functions from $X \to Y$

I know that $||F(x)|| \leq ||F||.||x||$, which gives us $||x|| \geq \frac{\alpha}{||F||}$. This is true for all $x$ in that set, so it will be true for the $infimum$ as well.

How to show the other inequality i.e. $inf\{||x|| : x \in X , ||F(x)|| = \alpha\} \leq \frac{\alpha}{||F||}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\alpha = 0$, then we have $\{ ||x ||: ||F x || = 0 \} = \{ 0 \}$, so equality holds. Thus suppose $\alpha > 0$.

We have $|| F || = \sup \{ \frac{||F x|| }{||x||}: x \neq 0\} $.
So for all $||F || > \epsilon > 0$ we can find an $x \in X$ such that $||F x || \ge (||F || - \epsilon )|| x ||$. If we scale $x$ such that $||F x|| = \alpha$, we have $\alpha \ge (||F|| - \epsilon ) ||x||$, which is equivalent with $||x|| \le \frac{ \alpha }{||F|| - \epsilon }$.

Let $\epsilon \to 0$ to obtain the upper bound.